# Touch en bash script no funciona

Tags: bash, touch

estoy teniendo problemas con el uso de touch en un script de bash. Si ejecuto en la terminal:

```
touch file{1..4}
```

me crea los archivos `file1 file2 file3 file4`

pero si lo uso en un script de bash el comportamiento es distinto

```
#! /bin/bash
touch file{1..4}
```

me crea solo un archivo con nombre `file{1..4}`

Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: nótese que sobra el espacio entre `#!` y `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Resulta que si ejecuto el script mediante `sh script.sh` no funciona, pero si le doy permiso de ejecucion con `chmod +x script.sh` y al ejecutarlo `./script.sh` genera los 4 archivos.

¿Alguien experimientado que me orienta porque no funciona de la otra forma?

Comment: Pues muy fácil: `sh script.sh` ejecuta **usando la shell `sh`**, mientras que de la otra forma sigue el *shebang* `/bin/bash` y lo ejecuta usando la shell `bash`. Y adivina cual de las 2 shell **no tiene** soporte para la síntaxis `{1..4} `

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!